# git checkout master error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

So I've created a new rails app  `rails new myapp` then then a `cd myapp` and then `git init` and then `git checkout -b experimental` - it created new branch just fine, and as I tried switch back to the master it did not work and I get the error that's in the title, also `git branch` - nothing, so I did chceck and the branches folder is empty as I expected?

Answer (score 10):

Your first branch is not created until your first commit is made.  If you simply `git init` and immediately switch to a new branch, you will not have created a `master` branch.  For example:

```
% git init .
% git branch
```

Shows that you do not have any branches.  If you are to switch branches, you will change the branch that will be committed to (and therefore created) when you create your first commit.  However you can see that this still does not show as a branch that exists:

```
% git checkout -b experimental
% git branch
```

Still shows no branches.  However when you create your first commit:

```
% echo hello > newfile.txt
% git add newfile.txt
% git commit -mexperimental
[experimental (root-commit) dab457a] experimental
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 newfile.txt
```

Now the `experimental` branch exists, though `master` does not, since you did not commit to it:

```
% git branch
* experimental
```

---

The error message you received is particularly dense, as you can use `git checkout` to either switch to a different branch, or to write a file to the working directory.  When you run:

```
% git checkout master
```

This is *first* interpreted as "switch to the `master` branch".  Lacking a `master` branch, however, it is *then* interpreted as "check out the file `master` to the working directory".  Since you also lack that, it tells you that it could not find a file (or, really, a [pathspec](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html)) `master`.